# Transform txt file into string

Tags: android, file

I have downloaded a `txt file` from Firebase, and I have the path and everything, and I'm trying to convert this file into a String, so I can set all the content of the file to another method

i have tried this

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                        try {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myTxtFile));
                            String line;

                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                text.append(line);
                                text.append('\n');
                            }
                            Log.e("OUTPUTSTRING",""+br);
                            br.close();

                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                        }
```

but in my log I cant see the content of the file, instead, it returns this

> java.io.BufferedReader@5eb1add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're logging `br` which is an object of `BufferedReader`. You probably want to build the string using `text.toString()` and log it.